# Render D3 Hierarchical Edge Bundling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, server-side-rendering, hierarchical-clustering

After successfully forking the D3 Hierarchical Edge Bundle here: (https://observablehq.com/@logic-based/hierarchical-edge-bundling) I'm now trying to transfer the rendering to private HTML files, so that I can create new versions of the charts and share them with internal colleagues.

I've done this with the radial dendrogram, but with the edge bundling, I'm stuck on the rendering issue for HEB.  Below I'm re-purposing the return block from the dendrogram (see asterisks), but I'm thinking that's wrong?
I've excluded the data here, but the console.log for data shows that it is being formatted successfully.
I've also excluded the CSS portion, but I've re-purposed the observable CSS for now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="en-us" width="2600" height="2800">
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hierarchy.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

const line = d3.lineRadial()
    .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
    .radius(d => d.y)
    .angle(d => d.x)


let colorin = "#00f"
let colorout = "#f00"
let colornone = "#ccc"
let width = 954
let radius = width / 2


const tree = d3.cluster()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius - 100])

const root = tree(bilink(d3.hierarchy(data)
      .sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.height, b.height) || d3.ascending(a.data.name, b.data.name))));


const svg = d3.create("svg")


const node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .join("g")
    .attr("transform", d => `rotate(${d.x * 180 / Math.PI - 90}) translate(${d.y},0)`)
    .append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("x", d => d.x < Math.PI ? 6 : -6)
      .attr("text-anchor", d => d.x < Math.PI ? "start" : "end")
      .attr("transform", d => d.x >= Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : null)
      .text(d => d.data.name)
      .each(function(d) { d.text = this; })
      .on("mouseover", overed)
      .on("mouseout", outed)
      .call(text => text.append("title").text(d => `${id(d)}
        ${d.outgoing.length} outgoing
        ${d.incoming.length} incoming`))
        console.log("node", node);

const link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", colornone)
      .attr("fill", "none")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(root.leaves().flatMap(leaf => leaf.outgoing))
    .join("path")
      .style("mix-blend-mode", "multiply")
      .attr("d", ([i, o]) => line(i.path(o)))
      .each(function(d) { d.path = this; })
      console.log("node", link);

console.log("svg", svg);

  function overed(d) {
    link.style("mix-blend-mode", null);
    d3.select(this).attr("font-weight", "bold");
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", colorin).raise();
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(([d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", colorin).attr("font-weight", "bold");
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", colorout).raise();
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(([, d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", colorout).attr("font-weight", "bold");
  }

  function outed(d) {
    link.style("mix-blend-mode", "multiply");
    d3.select(this).attr("font-weight", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(([d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", null).attr("font-weight", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(([, d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", null).attr("font-weight", null);
  }


// are these the lines I need to render?  In observable, all the code is held within a chart object and returned to a chart rendering function

**d3.selectAll('g.node').attr("id", function(d,i){ return "node"+i})
d3.selectAll('path.link').attr("id", function(d,i){ return "link"+i})**


function hierarchy(data, delimiter = ".") {
  let root;
  const map = new Map;
  data.forEach(function find(data) {
    const {name} = data;
    if (map.has(name)) return map.get(name);
    const i = name.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
    map.set(name, data);
    if (i >= 0) {
      find({name: name.substring(0, i), children: []}).children.push(data);
      data.name = name.substring(i + 1);
    } else {
      root = data;
    }
    return data;
  });
  return root;

}


function bilink(root) {
  const map = new Map(root.leaves().map(d => [id(d), d]));
  for (const d of root.leaves()) {
      d.incoming = [];
      console.log(d.data);
      d.outgoing = d.data.imports.map(i => [d, map.get(i)]);
  }
  for (const d of root.leaves()) for (const o of d.outgoing) o[1].incoming.push(o);
  return root;
}

function id(node) {
  return `${node.parent ? id(node.parent) + "." : ""}${node.data.name}`;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it turns out that Observable has their own export process, and that is helpful, but is not entirely pliable.  I think I am close with this separate solution, but not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

Whew!  I figured this out myself.
Essentially, I had most of the code in the wrong order.  But I've finally gotten this working.

```
let colorin = "#00f"
let colorout = "#f00"

let colornone = "#ccc"

let width = 1200
let height = 1200
let radius = width / 2


const tree = d3.cluster()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius - 100])

const root = tree(bilink(d3.hierarchy(data)
    .sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.height, b.height) || d3.ascending(a.data.name, b.data.name))));


const line = d3.lineRadial()
    .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
    .radius(d => d.y)
    .angle(d => d.x)

 
const svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height",height)
  .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -width / 2, width, width]);
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + 110) + "," + (height / 2 + 110) + ")"); 


const node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .join("g")
    .attr("transform", d => `rotate(${d.x * 180 / Math.PI - 90}) translate(${d.y},0)`)
    .append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("x", d => d.x < Math.PI ? 6 : -6)
      .attr("text-anchor", d => d.x < Math.PI ? "start" : "end")
      .attr("transform", d => d.x >= Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : null)
      .text(d => d.data.name)
      .each(function(d) { d.text = this; })
      .on("mouseover", overed)
      .on("mouseout", outed)
      .call(text => text.append("title").text(d => `${id(d)}
        ${d.outgoing.length} outgoing
        ${d.incoming.length} incoming`))
        console.log("node", node);

const link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", colornone)
      .attr("fill", "none")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(root.leaves().flatMap(leaf => leaf.outgoing))
    .join("path")
      .style("mix-blend-mode", "multiply")
      .attr("d", ([i, o]) => line(i.path(o)))
      .each(function(d) { d.path = this; })
      console.log("node", link);
      
console.log("svg", svg);

  function overed(d) {
    link.style("mix-blend-mode", null);
    d3.select(this).attr("font-weight", "bold");
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", colorin).raise();
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(([d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", colorin).attr("font-weight", "bold");
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", colorout).raise();
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(([, d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", colorout).attr("font-weight", "bold");
  }

  function outed(d) {
    link.style("mix-blend-mode", "multiply");
    d3.select(this).attr("font-weight", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.incoming.map(([d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", null).attr("font-weight", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(d => d.path)).attr("stroke", null);
    d3.selectAll(d.outgoing.map(([, d]) => d.text)).attr("fill", null).attr("font-weight", null);
  }


function hierarchy(data, delimiter = ".") {
  let root;
  const map = new Map;
  data.forEach(function find(data) {
    const {name} = data;
    if (map.has(name)) return map.get(name);
    const i = name.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
    map.set(name, data);
    if (i >= 0) {
      find({name: name.substring(0, i), children: []}).children.push(data);
      data.name = name.substring(i + 1);
    } else {
      root = data;
    }
    return data;
  });
  return root;
  
}

function bilink(root) {
  const map = new Map(root.leaves().map(d => [id(d), d]));
  for (const d of root.leaves()) {
      d.incoming = [];
      console.log(d.data);
      d.outgoing = d.data.imports.map(i => [d, map.get(i)]);
  }
  for (const d of root.leaves()) for (const o of d.outgoing) o[1].incoming.push(o);
  return root;
}

function id(node) {
  return `${node.parent ? id(node.parent) + "." : ""}${node.data.name}`;
}`
```